# elasticsearch empty result after filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of geo locations saved in my elasticsearch and with a search like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

I get full results and everything works correct.
HOWEVER as soon as I start restricting the search to any area (even if it's -100, -100 to 100, 100 like below:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_bounding_box" : {
                    "location" : {
                        "top_left" : "-100, -100",
                        "bottom_right" : "100, 100"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all I get as a response is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [took] => 21
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 4
            [successful] => 4
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [max_score] => 
            [hits] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I'm running out of ideas on how to fix this so, anyone have any helpful advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the sollution to this, this is how I got it to work:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
"match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_polygon" : {
                    "location" : {
                        "points" : [
                            "10,10",
                            "20, 10",
                            "20, 20",
                            "10, 20"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing only:

```
"query": { match_all: {} },
"filter" : {
  "geo_bounding_box" : {
   "location" : {
     "top_left" : "-100, -100",
      "bottom_right" : "100, 100"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this gives me "No query registered for [filter]"

Comment: back to empty result, this did however lead me to a sollution, I'll post it below, thanks for the help though

Comment: yep sure, have fun with ES